# Bash script runs one command before previous. I want them one after the other

Tags: linux, bash

So part of my script is as follows:

```
ssh user@$remoteServer "
    cd ~/a/b/c/;
    echo -e 'blah blah'
    sleep 1 # Added this just to make sure it waits.
    foo=`grep something xyz.log |sed 's/something//g' |sed 's/something-else//g'`
    echo $foo > ~/xyz.list
    exit "
```

In my output I see:

```
grep: xyz.log: No such file or directory
blah blah
```

Whereas when I ssh to the server, xyz.log does exist within ~/a/b/c/

Why is the grep statement getting executed before the echo statement?

Can someone please help?

Comment: BTW, a few notes -- any shell where `echo -e` doesn't print `-e` on output is defying the POSIX standard. Leave out `-e` if you can, or use `printf '%b' "..."` instead if you can't. See the spec for echo at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Comment: ...also, backticks are deprecated in favor of `$()` for good reason: Backslashes inside them need to be doubled up to still have effect. If you have any variable expansions inside your assignment to `foo`, you'll *really* want to use `$()` syntax instead of the backticks.

Comment: ...also, quotes are important. `echo $foo`, to give you an example, will replace any whitespace-surrounded `*` in `$foo` with a list of files in the current directory. Use `echo "$foo"` instead, and consider making a habit of running code through http://shellcheck.net/ to find this kind of error.

Comment: err, `printf '%b\n' "..."` instead if you can't, unless what you wanted was equivalent to `echo -n` as well.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I did use $() before i tried back-ticks. I changed to back-ticks because I thought $() was the issue. Also thanks for shellcheck.net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that your command in backticks is being run **locally**, not on the remote end of the SSH connection. Thus, it runs before you've even connected to the remote system at all! (This is true for all expansions that run in double-quotes, so the `$foo` in `echo $foo` as well).

Use a quoted heredoc to protect your code against local evaluation:

```
ssh user@$remoteServer bash -s <<'EOF'
    cd ~/a/b/c/;
    echo -e 'blah blah'
    sleep 1 # Added this just to make sure it waits.
    foo=`grep something xyz.log |sed 's/something//g' |sed 's/something-else//g'`
    echo $foo > ~/xyz.list
    exit
EOF
```

If you want to pass through a variable from the local side, the easy way is with positional parameters:

```
printf -v varsStr '%q ' "$varOne" "$varTwo"
ssh "user@$remoteServer" "bash -s $varsStr" <<'EOF'
  varOne=$1; varTwo=$2 # set as remote variables
  echo "Remote value of varOne is $varOne"
  echo "Remote value of varTwo is $varTwo"
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked but the only problem I am facing now is I cannot access a variable defined outside the ssh. For ex:  
 `k=$(echo "$j" |awk -F / '{print $2}')  
  echo "value of k out of ssh is $k" $ This prints correct value  
      ssh ipbx@$remoteServer bash -s <<- 'EOF'  
                cd ~/a/b/c/;  
                echo "value of k in ssh is $k" #This is blank  
                foo=$(grep something "$k".log.1 |sed ...) #grep: .log.1: No such file or directory`

Comment: Edit: I suck at formatting. But I hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

[command server] ------> [remote server]

The better way is to create shell script in the "remote server" , and run the command in the "command server" such as :

```
ssh ${remoteserver} "/bin/bash /foo/foo.sh"
```

It will solve many problem , the aim is to make things simple but not complex .

Comment: I'm not actually sure I agree that your proposal succeeds at making things simpler. Copying a file to your remote server before executing it there means you need to have scripts that check whether the copy succeeded; you need to make sure that the copy is up-to-date and a stale version can't be used instead in the event of failures; you need to have policy around whether you clean them up when finished; etc.

Comment: ...whereas piping raw script text over SSH avoids all of those complexities: There's no separate out-of-band copy process, and you can't possibly be running anything other than what's coming in on stdin.

Comment: (Also, if you use a world-writable place like `/tmp` for such scripts, you need to be worried about symlink attacks by unprivileged users if the names you use for those scripts are known; yet more complexity!).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , I agree your words , but security is another field not in this problem , if the remoteserver is not safe , so you do everything is not safe .

Comment: There are different levels of "not safe" -- maintaining the boundaries between those levels is what preventing privilege escalation is all about.

Comment: ...my larger point, though, is that to do the copy-and-run thing right (handling all your boundary conditions, be they security attacks or merely filesystems that are out of space or sporadic network failures tripping up a leading copy attempt) requires care and caution, which makes it -- by definition -- **not** the simpler approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , that's my point: (1)when we create shell scripts in the remoteserver , all command/resource/config that appear at the scripts are just depend on the remoteserver , not other servers , so the security level is same . (2) sometime the command is depend on tty and stdin , so create scripts is better .

Comment: And , for example , we have 3 web/php servers , we need to rsync (or other way) modified php files to all servers to put a patch , I think it's the same status to create or update the shell scripts ,  they are all code .