# Command substitution doesn't work in script text passed over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ls

I tried to use the following `bash` to access the content of a folder;

```
test_dir="/some_dir/dir_test"

ssh -t -t user@remote-host "
if [ -d '$test_dir' ]; then
    sudo chown -R user:admin '$test_dir'
    echo '$test_dir'/*
    if [ '$(ls -A $test_dir)' ]; then
        sudo rm -rf '$test_dir'/*
        echo '$test_dir'/*
fi"
```

the script tried to check if `/some_dir/dir_test` is empty or not, if not, delete all files in that folder; but I got the following error;

```
ls: cannot access '/some_dir/dir_test': No such file or directory

/some_dir/dir_test
drwxr-xr-x.  3 sys admin   16 Sep 23 15:03 dir_test
```

However, I can `ssh` to `remote-host` and `ls -A /some_dir/dir_test`.

I am wondering how to fix it.

Comment: Note that single quotes don't suffice to quote unknown filenames -- filenames on UNIX are allowed to contain single quotes, and if someone runs `mkdir $'/some_dir/$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''`, you don't want that directory name being turned into a command when it's passed over SSH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(ls -A $test_dir)` is being executed locally on the client, not the server. You need to escape the `$`. You'll also need to use `"` around it, otherwise the command substitution won't be executed.

```
    if [ \"\$(ls -A $test_dir)\" ]; then
```

Often the best way to execute multiline commands is to use `scp` to copy a script to the remote machine, then use `ssh` to execute the script. Mixing local and remote expansion of variables and command substitutions gets complicated, especially when you need to quote them.

Comment: ...or one might switch to using a quoted heredoc and pass `test_dir` on ssh's argument list, so the code in the heredoc doesn't need the munging.

Comment: How would you get `test_dir` from ssh's argument list into the remote command?

Comment: `printf -v test_dir_q '%q' "$test_dir"; ssh ...host... "bash -s $test_dir_q" <<'EOF'`; I can find some other answers where I've expanded on that pattern, given a minute...

Comment: Here's such an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025832/14122

Comment: Another is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839661/how-to-traverse-path-using-variable-in-linux-shells-script

Comment: That's still performing the variable substitution in the string `$test_dir_q`.

Comment: Sorry? The whole point of `printf %q` is that it generates text that evaluates to the argument's literal value (in a manner that covers all corner cases when the remote shell is bash -- including bash-as-`/bin/sh`, but still an important caveat), and `<<'EOF'` prevents any local substitution from happening before the text is passed to the remote end.

Comment: I see, `%q` is new to me. Feel free to post an answer showing how to put this all together.

Comment: I already have, in the answers to other questions linked above; I'm frankly a bit hard-pressed not to see this one as a duplicate. If there's some aspect to this question that isn't covered in them, could you call it out to me explicitly?